# Как получается ответ 2

Tags: java

```
int n = 33;
int s = 0;
while (n > 0) {
  s += n % 2;
  n /= 2;
}
System.out.println(s); // Ответ: 2   <- Почему?
```

Comment: А что не так-то?

Comment: Для начала нужно знать что должно обозначать s, если 2 - неправильный ответ

Comment: Это код подсчета количества единичных битов в двоичном представлении числа. В двоичном представлении числа 33 два единичных бита.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При первом заходе в цикл `n % 2` - даст остаток `1`, `s` теперь равно `1`. Все последующие итерации при делении на 2 дают целое число (остаток `0`). `s` не меняется.

На предпоследней итерации, когда `n = 2`, после `n /= 2` в `n` будет `1`. В `s` всё ещё `1`.

На последней итерации `n % 2` - даст остаток `1`, `s` теперь равно `2`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @HelloGoogle рад помочь (: